# Finding Jordan form of differentiation map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Consider the space $V$ spanned over $\mathbb{R}$ by $\{1,x,e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x,x^3e^x\}$ and let $D:V \rightarrow V$ be the differentiation map. I need to show that $D$ maps $V \rightarrow V$ and find the Jordan form of $D$ on $V$.

 To show it spans, I need to show $im(D)$ contains all basis vectors of $V$. We have:
$$D(1)=0$$
$$D(x)=1$$
$$D(e^x)=e^x$$
$$D(xe^x)=e^x+xe^x$$
$$D(x^2e^x)=2xe^x+x^2e^x$$
$$D(x^3e^x)=3x^2e^x+x^3e^x$$
By considering linear combinations of these, I can see that $im(D)$ contains $1,e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x,x^3e^x$, but it does not contain $x$. I am confused about this.
Also, how do I find the Jordan form of $D$?

Comment: why do you have to show the image of $D$ spans $V$? You just have to show that the image of $D$ is contained in $V$ (which you already did) so that it is actually well-defined to consider differentiation as a mapping $D:V\to V$ (because a-priori, $D$ maps $V$ into the set of all (say differentiable) functions $\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$). Note that when we write $f:X\to Y$, it doesn't mean the function has to be surjective.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.